# How do I set up PouchDB with Sapper?

Tags: pouchdb, rollup, svelte, sapper

I have a project built with [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev), and I'm using Rollup as the bundler. I've been trying to set up PouchDB to work with my app, but with `pouchdb-browser`, `pouchdb-find`, and `relational-pouch` installed as dev dependencies, the build always crashes with a `fetch is not defined` error.

I'm sure this is because I am not familiar enough with how Rollup and Sapper works. From my understanding, it's because Sapper is performing SSR, and in the server's context, `fetch` is not defined. If this is indeed the case, how do I configure Rollup/Sapper to resolve this build error?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on where and how you actually setup `pouchdb` in your app?